# Levenstein program variance?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

I have a C++ task and I'm not sure how to approach this problem. 
So you have a startString and an ENDSTRING. The point is to transform the startString into ENDSTRING with the given set of operations:

1. insert character
2. detele character
3. replace substring from dictionary
4. move substring (to the left)
5. reverse substring

AND the operations you use should be as low as possible

So I searched google to see that this is the string reconstruction problem.
This is the edit distance and particularly the Levenshtein distance algorithm.

BUT Levenshtein algorithm does NOT give you the steps you make - it gives you only the number of steps. I have to write an algorithm to reconstruct the givenString to the ENDSTRING with minimum operations as possible and to write a file which describes the steps taken so far.

Can you please guide me which algorithm should I use because that Levenshtein one only gives you the number of steps, but I need their number as well **and a list with the actual steps.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you would have to modify the Levishtein algorithm a bit. As it is an example of Dynamic Programming, the calculation of one specific state of the Dynamic Program state space corresponds to a specific choice of alternatives. To my understanding, you have two options:

1.) use some auxiliary data strucute where for each state you store the choice to which its 
value corresponds;

2.) use no auxiliary data strucuture, but as soon as the sate space is evaluated, you use backtracking to see which choices have been possible.

Option 2.) might result in less code, but option 1.) might be easier to understand.

Comment: "Write a program which by a given starting and desired string, does a number of operations so that the final sequence is as close as possible to the desired one" Can you please refer me to some examples?